# Multiple Row to One Row Making One Field Array?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

There may be an answer similar to this but I have spent over an hour searching and trying to establish a similarity. There are lots on grouping but none can do what I need.

Essentially I want to take multiple rows and make them into one row merging the only column with different values into an array. I am sure the pictures will help:

### The current SQL is:

```
SELECT mu.`firstname`AS firstname,
mu.`lastname`AS lastname,
mu.`username`AS username,
tu.`tagid` AS tagID
FROM user mu
LEFT JOIN tag_usertags tu ON (tu.`userid`= mu.`id`)
WHERE mu.id=10
```

### At the moment:

```
----------------------------------------------------
|firstname | lastname     | username     | tagId   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|Manager . | User  ....   |   manager..  |    2    |
|Manager . | User ....    |   manager..  |   11    |
|Manager . | User    .... |   manager..  |   46    |
|Manager . | User    .....|   manager..  |   8     |
|Manager . | User  ....   |   manager..  |   31    |
|Manager . | User    .... |   manager..  |   13    |
|Manager . | User   ....  |   manager..  |   41    |
```

### What I would like to see:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|firstname | lastname       | username     |       tagId           |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Manager.  | User  ......   |   manager..  | 2,11,46,8,31,13,41    |
```

Comment: Can you explain why the current result set is not satisfactory? I don't see the practical application of your expected output, but if you still want it that way, you could get it done through cursors.

Comment: In reality there will be multiple ID's selected but there is no need to overcomplicate it on here as it makes it more difficult for people trying to do the same thing as me work that out. Ende Neu found the perfect answer with group_concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT mu.`firstname`AS firstname,
  mu.`lastname`AS lastname,
  mu.`username`AS username,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tu.`tagid` SEPARATOR ',') AS tagID
FROM user mu
LEFT JOIN tag_usertags tu ON (tu.`userid`= mu.`id`)
WHERE mu.id=10
GROUP BY mu.`firstname`
```

Comment: This does look like the right thing, it keeps erroring though on line 4 GROUP_CONCAT(tu.tagid... Any ideas?

Comment: @JoshJamesWillcock I probably made a mistake in the group concat, I used backticks (``)instead of single quotes (''), I made an edit.

Comment: I am so used to seeing backticks in SQL I didn't notice myself... Thankyou so much for your help!